# How important is the sequence of functions?

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I have a made a user login/ registration program to verify data from and SQLite3 database. I had all the functions running correctly on a Tkinter GUI ie: I was able to register a new user and login using the the details. The registration process created a SQLite database against which the login verification was performed.

Everything was working okay when I Just had the Users table running as my reference.

I then made some changes in order to neaten up the code and run the code from top to bottom (Startup -> Registration -> Login -> Login success -> Main App) in the sequence that is would normally run.

I did the following:

1.Added the app_start function in order to be able to destroy the initial main_screen. Run the app_start function as the mainloop() instead of the main_screen function.

2. Restructured the code to the sequence that it would run in terms of GUI's.
3. Made additional user entries on the "Registration page" for further information gathering and created a new table.

The code now creates blank database entries and as a result the login function is not working.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import os
import time
import datetime
import sqlite3

screensize = "500x500"
popsize = "150x150"


conn = sqlite3.connect('UserInfo.db')
c = conn.cursor()


def main_screen():
    global screen
    screen = Tk()
    screen.geometry('300x200')
    screen.title("Main Screen")
    Label(text = "LOGIN PAGE", bg = "grey", width = "300", height = "2", font = ("Calibri", 12)).pack()
    Label(text = "").pack()
    Button(text = "Login", height = "2", width = "30", command = Login).pack()
    Label(text = "").pack()
    Button(text = "Register", height = "2", width = "30" , command = register).pack()


def register():
    global screen1
    screen1 = Tk()
    screen1.title("Register")
    screen1.geometry(screensize)

    global username
    global password
    global Firstname
    global Surname
    global Registrationnumber


    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()
    Firstname = StringVar()
    Surname = StringVar()
    Registrationnumber = StringVar()


    Label(screen1, text = "Please enter details below", font = ("Calibiri", 20)).place(x = 10, y = 50)
    Label(screen1, text = "")

    Label(screen1,text = "First Name / Company name*").place(x = 10, y = 120)
    global Firstname_entry
    Firstname_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = Firstname)
    Firstname_entry.place(x = 250, y = 120)

    Label(screen1,text = "Surname*").place(x = 10, y = 155)
    global Surname_entry
    Surname_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = Surname)
    Surname_entry.place(x = 250, y = 155)

    Label(screen1,text = "Registration number*").place( x = 10, y = 185)
    global Registrationnumber_entry
    Registrationnumber_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = Registrationnumber)
    Registrationnumber_entry.place(x = 250, y = 185)

    Label(screen1,text = "Username *").place(x = 10, y = 220)
    global username_entry
    username_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = username)
    username_entry.place(x = 250, y = 220)

    Label(screen1,text = "Password*").place(x = 10, y = 255)
    global password_entry
    password_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = password)
    password_entry.place(x = 250, y = 255)

    Button(screen1, text = "Register user now", command = register_user).place(x = 200, y = 300)
    Button(screen1, text = "Go to login", command = Login).place(x = 200, y = 350)


def register_user():


    Firstname_info = Firstname.get()
    Surname_info = Surname.get()
    Registrationnumber_info = Registrationnumber.get()
    username_info = username.get()
    password_info = password.get()

    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User_Information (Firstname TEXT , Surname TEXT , Registration TEXT, Username TEXT, Password TEXT )")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO User_Information (Firstname, Surname, Registration, Username, Password) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (Firstname_info, Surname_info, Registrationnumber_info, username_info, password_info))

    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (Username TEXT NOT NULL, Password TEXT NOT NULL)")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password) VALUES(?, ?)", (username_info, password_info, ))

    conn.commit()

    User_registered()

    Firstname_entry.delete(0, END)
    Surname_entry.delete(0, END)
    Registrationnumber_entry.delete(0, END)
    username_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)


def User_registered():
    screen5 = Tk()
    screen5.title("Registration Complete")
    screen5.geometry(popsize)
    incorrect = Label(screen5, text = "User has been registered")
    incorrect.pack()
    Button(screen5, text = "okay", command = screen5.destroy).pack()

def Login():
    global screen2
    screen2 = Tk()
    screen2.title("Login")
    screen2.geometry(screensize)

    Label(screen2, text = "Please enter details to login").pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "").pack()

    global username_verify
    global password_verify

    username_verify = StringVar()
    password_verify = StringVar()

    Label(screen2, text = "Username").pack()
    global username_entry1
    username_entry1 = Entry(screen2, textvariable = username_verify)
    username_entry1.pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "Password").pack()
    global password_entry1
    password_entry1 = Entry(screen2, textvariable = password_verify)
    password_entry1.pack()
    Label(text = "")
    Button(screen2, text = "Login now",width = 10, height = 2, command = fetch_login).pack()
    Button(screen2, text = "Register new User", command = register).pack()
    screen.destroy()

def fetch_login():

    Uname = username_entry1.get()# Entry from UI
    Pword = password_entry1.get()# Entry from UI

    a = (Uname,)#Converting entry to tuple to match table data
    b = (Pword, )#Converting entry to tuple to match table data
    d = (a + b)
    print(d)
    print(type(d))# To ensure that entry is now a tuple


    c.execute('SELECT * FROM Users')
    data = c.fetchall()

    for row in data:
        print(row)# To see what SQLite3 table data is being drawn

    if d in data:
        c.execute('SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Username = ?',(a))
        pdata = c.fetchall()
        print(pdata)        
        if b in pdata:
            Login_success()
        else:
            password_incorrect()
    else:
        User_not_found()


def password_incorrect():
    screen4 = Tk()
    screen4.title("ERROR!")
    screen4.geometry(popsize)
    incorrect = Label(screen4, text = "Password incorrect!")
    incorrect.pack()
    Button(screen4, text = "okay", command = screen4.destroy).pack()



def User_not_found():
    screen5 = Tk()
    screen5.title("ERROR!")
    screen5.geometry("300x100")
    not_found = Label(screen5, text = "User not found or password incorrect!")
    not_found.pack()
    Button(screen5, text = "okay", command = screen5.destroy).pack()



def Login_success():
    Main_Page() 

    screen2.destroy()

def Main_Page():
    global screen3
    screen3 = Tk()
    screen3.geometry(screensize)
    screen3.title("Main Page")

    menubar = tk.Menu(screen3)
    Filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)

    Filemenu.add_command(label = "Add Asset", command = Add_Asset)
    Filemenu.add_separator()

    Filemenu.add_command(label = "Dispose Asset", command = Dipose_Asset)
    Filemenu.add_separator()

    Filemenu.add_command(label = "Edit Asset", command = Edit_Asset)
    Filemenu.add_separator()


    Filemenu.add_command(label = "Exit", command = quit)
    Filemenu.add_separator()



    menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = Filemenu)


    screen3.config(menu=menubar)

def Add_Asset():
    print("Asset Added")

def Dipose_Asset():
    print("Dispose Asset")  

def Edit_Asset():
    print("Asset Added")



def app_start():
    main_screen()
    mainloop()

app_start()
```

I am new to programming. Any advice regarding the password verification process would be appreceiated. I have had to convert my entries to tuples in order to compare them to the data from the table.

This is the original code when it worked.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import os
import time
import datetime
import sqlite3

screensize = "500x500"
popsize = "150x150"


conn = sqlite3.connect('UserInfo.db')
c = conn.cursor()


def register():
    global screen1
    screen1 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen1.title("Register")
    screen1.geometry(screensize)

    global username
    global password
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()

    Label(screen1, text = "Please enter details below")
    Label(screen1, text = "")
    Label(screen1,text = "Username *").pack()
    global username_entry
    username_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = username)
    username_entry.pack()
    Label(screen1,text = "password *").pack()
    global password_entry
    password_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = password)
    password_entry.pack()
    Button(screen1, text = "Register user now", command = 
    register_user).pack()
    Button(screen1, text = "Go to login", command = Login).pack()


def register_user():

    username_info = username.get()
    password_info = password.get()

    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (Username TEXT NOT NULL, 
    Password TEXT NOT NULL)")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password) VALUES(?, ?)", 
    (username_info, password_info, ))

    conn.commit()


    User_registered()

    username_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)

def User_registered():
    screen5 = Tk()
    screen5.title("Registration Complete")
    screen5.geometry(popsize)
    incorrect = Label(screen5, text = "User has been registered")
    incorrect.pack()
    Button(screen5, text = "okay", command = screen5.destroy).pack()

def Login():
    global screen2
    screen2 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen2.title("Login")
    screen2.geometry(screensize)

    Label(screen2, text = "Please enter details to login").pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "").pack()

    global username_verify
    global password_verify

    username_verify = StringVar()
    password_verify = StringVar()

    Label(screen2, text = "Username").pack()
    global username_entry1
    username_entry1 = Entry(screen2, textvariable = username_verify)
    username_entry1.pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "Password").pack()
    global password_entry1
    password_entry1 = Entry(screen2, textvariable = password_verify)
    password_entry1.pack()
    Label(text = "")
    Button(screen2, text = "Login now",width = 10, height = 2, command = 
    fetch_login).pack()
    Button(screen2, text = "Register new User", command = register).pack()


def fetch_login():

    Uname = username_entry1.get()# Entry from UI
    Pword = password_entry1.get()# Entry from UI

    a = (Uname,)#Converting entry to tuple to match table data
    b = (Pword, )#Converting entry to tuple to match table data
    d = (a + b)
    print(d)
    print(type(d))# To ensure that entry is now a tuple


    c.execute('SELECT * FROM Users')
    data = c.fetchall()

    for row in data:
        print(row)# To see what SQLite3 table data is being drawn

    if d in data:
        c.execute('SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Username = ?',(a))
        pdata = c.fetchall()
        print(pdata)        
        if b in pdata:
            Login_success()
        else:
            password_incorrect()
    else:
        User_not_found()


def password_incorrect():
    screen4 = Toplevel(screen2)
    screen4.title("ERROR!")
    screen4.geometry(popsize)
    incorrect = Label(screen4, text = "Password incorrect!")
    incorrect.pack()
    Button(screen4, text = "okay", command = screen4.destroy).pack()



def User_not_found():
    screen5 = Toplevel(screen2)
    screen5.title("ERROR!")
    screen5.geometry("300x100")
    not_found = Label(screen5, text = "User not found or password 
    incorrect!")
    not_found.pack()
    Button(screen5, text = "okay", command = screen5.destroy).pack()



def Login_success():
    Main_Page() 



def Main_Page():
    global screen3
    screen3 = Toplevel(screen2)
    screen3.geometry(screensize)
    screen3.title("Main Page")

    menubar = tk.Menu(screen3)
    Filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)

    Filemenu.add_command(label = "Add Asset", command = Add_Asset)
    Filemenu.add_separator()

    Filemenu.add_command(label = "Dispose Asset", command = Dipose_Asset)
    Filemenu.add_separator()

    Filemenu.add_command(label = "Edit Asset", command = Edit_Asset)
    Filemenu.add_separator()


    Filemenu.add_command(label = "Exit", command = quit)
    Filemenu.add_separator()



    menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = Filemenu)


    screen3.config(menu=menubar)

def Add_Asset():
    print("Asset Added")

def Dipose_Asset():
    print("Dispose Asset")  

def Edit_Asset():
    print("Asset Added")


def main_screen():
    global screen
    screen = Tk()
    screen.geometry(screensize)
    screen.title("Main Screen")
    Label(text = "Notes", bg = "grey", width = "300", height = "2", font = 
    ("Calibri", 12)).pack()
    Label(text = "").pack()
    Button(text = "Login", height = "2", width = "30", command = 
    Login).pack()
    Label(text = "").pack()
    Button(text = "Register", height = "2", width = "30" , command = 
    register).pack()

    screen.mainloop()

main_screen()
```

The difference is mainly "Toplevel" I had changed each definition to have its own screen = Tk() so I could destroy each page once it had entered data and "Registered" or "Logged in"

Comment: How are you calling your functions? Nothing is being executed in your code since you are only showing us the definitions. And can you show us what it looked like before?

Comment: Indent error on this line `if b in pdata:`